# Why register many similar marks?

Tags: trademark

Many companies apply for multiple registrations for the same term and similar goods and services, is that worthwhile? For example, Starbucks owns dozens of registrations for "Starbucks" both as standard character marks and as stylized designs. It would seem that a single registration would already prevent others from using the name for related products and services. Why is it worthwhile to apply for many registrations for the same term in reference to similar goods and services?

Answer (score 3):

Registering the text string Starbucks" should prevent anyone else using it in any font for related products. However, I do not think it is useful against "Startducks" that is printed in the standard logo in Starbucks green. With the stylized version, you cover things that misleadingly look like what you see on a Starbucks building.